# Unable to resume activity, java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

As you can see this is my code, I built an applications in which I used several permission methods without any problem. In this case, I only have just one activity in order to get the user location, but it gives me an error while it wants to return the request permission result.

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var geofencingClient: GeofencingClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    map = googleMap
    map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

    if (!isLocationPermissionGranted()) {
        val permissions = mutableListOf(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        )
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            permissions.toTypedArray(),
            LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE
        )
    } else {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        }
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        // Zoom to last known location
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it != null) {
                with(map) {
                    val latLng = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
                    moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, CAMERA_ZOOM_LEVEL))
                }
            } else {
                with(map) {
                    moveCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            LatLng(65.01355297927051, 25.464019811372978),
                            CAMERA_ZOOM_LEVEL
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    setLongClick(map)
    setPoiClick(map)
}

private fun setPoiClick(map: GoogleMap) {
    map.setOnPoiClickListener { poi ->
        map.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .position(poi.latLng)
                .title(poi.name)
        )?.showInfoWindow()

        scheduleJob()
    }
}

private fun setLongClick(map: GoogleMap) {
    map.setOnMapLongClickListener { latlng ->

        map.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
                .title("Current location")
        )?.showInfoWindow()
        map.addCircle(
            CircleOptions()
                .center(latlng)
                .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70, 70, 70))
                .fillColor(Color.argb(70, 150, 150, 150))
                .radius(GEOFENCE_RADIUS.toDouble())
        )
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, CAMERA_ZOOM_LEVEL))

        val database = Firebase.database
        val reference = database.getReference("reminders")
        val key = reference.push().key
        if (key != null) {
            val reminder = Reminder(key, latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude)
            reference.child(key).setValue(reminder)
        }
        createGeoFence(latlng, key!!, geofencingClient)
    }
}

@SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag", "MissingPermission")
private fun createGeoFence(location: LatLng, key: String, geofencingClient: GeofencingClient) {
    val geofence = Geofence.Builder()
        .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_ID)
        .setCircularRegion(location.latitude, location.longitude, GEOFENCE_RADIUS.toFloat())
        .setExpirationDuration(GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION.toLong())
        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
        .setLoiteringDelay(GEOFENCE_DWELL_DELAY)
        .build()

    val geofenceRequest = GeofencingRequest.Builder()
        .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
        .addGeofence(geofence)
        .build()

    val intent = Intent(this, GeofenceReceiver::class.java)
        .putExtra("key", key)
        .putExtra("message", "Geofence alert - ${location.latitude}, ${location.longitude}")

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        applicationContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                ),
                GEOFENCE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        } else {
            geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofenceRequest, pendingIntent)
        }
    } else {
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofenceRequest, pendingIntent)
    }
}

private fun isLocationPermissionGranted() : Boolean {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == GEOFENCE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (permissions.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "This application needs background location to work on Android 10 and higher",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (
            grantResults.isNotEmpty() && (
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                return
            }
            map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            onMapReady(map)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "The app needs location permission to function",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[2] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "This application needs background location to work on Android 10 and higher",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

companion object {
    fun removeGeofences(context: Context, triggeringGeofenceList: MutableList<Geofence>) {
        val geofenceIdList = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (entry in triggeringGeofenceList) {
            geofenceIdList.add(entry.requestId)
        }
        LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context).removeGeofences(geofenceIdList)
    }

    fun showNotification(context: Context?, message: String) {
        val CHANNEL_ID = "REMINDER_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL"
        var notificationId = 1589
        notificationId += Random(notificationId).nextInt(1, 30)

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!.applicationContext, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(message)
            )
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            ).apply {
                description = context.getString(R.string.app_name)
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun scheduleJob() {
    val componentName = ComponentName(this, ReminderJobService::class.java)
    val info = JobInfo.Builder(321, componentName)
        .setRequiresCharging(false)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        .setPersisted(true)
        .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
        .build()

    val scheduler = getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
    val resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info)
    if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed")
        scheduleJob()
    }
}

private fun cancelJob() {
    val scheduler = getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
    scheduler.cancel(321)
    Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled")
}

private fun permissionGrant(){
    val permissions = mutableListOf(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    )
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this,
        permissions.toTypedArray(),
        LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE
    )
}
}
```

**here is the error message:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.adit.bangkit.plagroid/com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activities.MapsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=123, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.adit.bangkit.plagroid/com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activities.MapsActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property map has not been initialized
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3828)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3860)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=123, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.adit.bangkit.plagroid/com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activities.MapsActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property map has not been initialized
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3860) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
 Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property map has not been initialized
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activities.MapsActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MapsActivity.kt:257)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7749)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7594)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4416)
```

I tried to find a good solution but unfortunately I couldn't fine a right one. why it's happening and how should I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check map is initialized or not before using it in onRequestPermissionResult method.  map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            onMapReady(map) may creating crash.

Comment: MapsActivity and its properties must have been cleared by the system due to device running low on memory or "Don't keep activities" enabled in developer options. So you need to ensure those lateinit properties are actually initialled when you get back your permission result.